# How can I make Text View anchor's be on the leading edge on SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to make a "Card View" for cities in one of my apps. This card has a 'Text' view on the top right corner to show information. The Text will adjust itself based on the length of the string. However, I need the text to extend towards the leading edge instead of it extending from the center.

***Here is the view:***

[image]

I need the View to remain in this position and grow towards the pointing arrow. This is how it should look when a "short" string is added.

***Below is an example on how it looks if the string is longer.***

[image]

Noticed how the view expanded from the center and some of the view was hidden? I need it to remain align to the right leaving the space between the view and the edge.

Here is the code for this view, you may use it on a playground in Xcode. Keep in mind you may have to add an image to the Resources in the Playground to make it work.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct CityView: View {

    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "barcelona.png")!)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Barcelona")
                    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .medium))
                    .padding(.trailing, 75.0)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
               
                Text("Spain")
                    .font(.system(size: 13, weight: .regular))
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.secondary)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 49)
            .background(Color.white)
            .offset(y: 76)
            
            Text("Most Fly-thru")
                .frame(maxHeight: 32)
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .font(.system(size: 13, weight: .medium))
                .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                .background(
                    Capsule()
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.primary.opacity(0.8))
                )
                .offset(x: 38, y: -76)
        }
        .frame(width: 166, height: 201)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
        .overlay {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1.2)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(CityView())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving you a hint.

```
@ViewBuilder
private func makeText(_ text: String) -> some View {
    Text(text)
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.vertical, 8)
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.2), in: Capsule())
}


#Preview {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                makeText("this is top~~~")
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                makeText("this is bottom~~~")
                Spacer()
            }
        }.padding()
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    .background(Color.green)
}
```

[image: result]

And don't rely on offsets.

Comment: This is straight forward and very simple. I did follow Apple's tutorials and they seem to like to use the .offset for things like these.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some issues with your design.

1. You're trying to force the top and bottom text to fit the entire ZStack. However, your ZStack doesn't fit its content size. Try to comment out `.clipShape`, you'll see the image overwhelms the border.
2. You're fixing `offSet` for those views, so it cannot dynamically fit, i.e., another parent view in another scenario, if bigger or smaller.

So I suggest splitting it into two components. The contentView has an image and an overlay that has aligned top-trailing and bottom-leading `Text`s.

```swift
struct OverlayCityView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Barcelona")
                            .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .medium))
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.black)

                        Text("Spain")
                            .font(.system(size: 13, weight: .regular))
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.secondary)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }

            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Most Fly-thru")
                        .frame(maxHeight: 32)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                        .font(.system(size: 13, weight: .medium))
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                        .background(
                            Capsule()
                                .foregroundStyle(Color.primary.opacity(0.8))
                        )
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
    .padding(.all, 8) //<- Give padding for those Texts here
}
```

```swift
struct CityView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "barcelona.png")!)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 186, height: 200)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 40)
        }
        .overlay {
            OverlayCityView()
        }
        .overlay {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1.2)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. With SwiftUI it seems that there are many ways of implementing the same view. I resisted for a while but now I am learning it.

Comment: Yeah, try to separate it into small pieces and make it as dynamic as possible. Long way to go, take it easy.